# Java Seamframework - Restful URLs - How to?

Tags: java, seam, url-rewriting

I'm planning on starting a web project, and I've been searching for the best option. Ultimately I choose to stick with Java + Seam + J Boss AS + JPA Hibernate.

But regarding URL Rewriting its been a really long run, without many accomplishments.

I'll have a hierarchical structure, Ex. Category -> Sub-category -> Sub-sub-category.

Basically I want these to map like foo.com/category/sub-category/sub-sub-category

- What helps me accomplish this?
- What are other possibilities?
- How flexible is URL rewriting?
- Can I append non-hierarchical data into my url? Ex.. .../category/sub-category/type/sub-sub-category

My questions regarding flexibility are mainly because, RESTFUL is supposed to be core. So if URL rewriting isn't that flexible, I'll have to carefully think about my design.

Regards.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Seam's inbuilt URL rewriting, or if you'd like more flexibility in the rewrite rules, you can use the UrlRewriteFilter from http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/.  Examples of both below:

**Seam's inbuilt rewriting** (which prob uses the tuckey filter under the covers anyway)

First enable the url rewriting in the *components.xml* file

```
<web:rewrite-filter view-mapping="*.seam"/>
```

Next, add the rewrite rules to the *pages.xml* file

```
<page view-id="/home.xhtml">
    <rewrite pattern="/home/{category}/{sub-category}/{sub-sub-category}" />
</page>
```

In this case, an incoming url served as

```
/home/vehicles/cars/fords
```

Will be served as if it was a request for

```
/home.seam?category=vehicles&sub-category=cars&sub-sub-category=fords
```

In the same way, outbound url's will be converted if the page has the named request params available.

**Or you could use the Tucky UrlRewriteFilter as follows**

Add the Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter jar to your project which you can grab from here

[http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/#download)

Next add the filter your your *web.xml* file

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Finally add a file called *urlrewrite.xml* to your WEB-INF dir.  This file will define your rewrite rules.  You will probably want to be somewhat familiar with regex.  The file should looks as follows

^/home.seam?category=(.*)&sub-category=(.*)&sub-sub-category=(.*)$
       /home/$1/$2/$3

```
<rule match-type="wildcard">
   <from>/home\/$1\/$2\/$3</from>
   <to type="redirect">/home.seam?category=$1&sub-category=$2&sub-sub-category=$3</to>
</rule>
```

Seam doco is here - [Seam documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/events.html#d0e5032)

Tucky UrlRewriteFilter doco is here - [Tuckey RewriteFilter doco](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/index.html)

Comment: Looks like the markdown parser doesn't like my regex expressions ;)  Infact it stripped out a whole bunch of text.  I'll add it to another comment

Comment: Should be after 'The file should look as follows':

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
        PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN"
        "http://tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
       <from>^/home.seam?category=(.*)&sub-category=(.*)&sub-sub-category=(.*)$</from>
       <to type="redirect">/home/$1/$2/$3</to>
    </rule>

Should continue with '<rule match-type...'

Answer (score 1):

I use [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) to handle the mapping of resources. I've not tried it with Seam, but I understand they fit well together.

Update: Someone has created an [example project](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBSEAM-422) showing how to integrate them and an associated [forum post](http://www.jboss.org/index.html?module=bb&op=viewtopic&p=3978556).

The [Restlet 2.0 Tutorial](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/tutorial#part10) describes how to handle URL rewriting and redirection.

Answer (score 1):

URI construction is orthogonal to REST. See: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: Indeed. Rather than calling such URIs "RESTful" one might call them "cool URIs" (an asinine name--but an established, correct one).

Answer (score 1):

What about other options for url rewriting?

Prettyfaces?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same frameworks you are planning to use (Java + Seam + J Boss AS + JPA Hibernate), and also RestFul webservices are my core.

I choose resteasy as the rest frameworks and it works just fine and easy (both to rewrite and to test, same as easymock). Also it is a jboss product and works fine with seam, easy to integrate.

As a sample code:

```
@Path("/webservice")

public class Web
{

    @GET
    @Path("{web}")
    @ProduceMime("application/xml")
    public String test(@QueryParam("param") String param, @PathParam("web") String web) 
{
//  code here
}
}
```

- `@Path` is your "root path" of the class (your real "root" would be configured on `components.xml`)
- `@GET` is from Rest
- `ProduceMime` or `ConsumeMime` is the mime you should consume or produce
- `@QueryParam` is the params of the URL and `@PathParam` the parameters you should get

So this get will receive a call from `/webservice/web?param=lalala` and return a string in the `application/xml` format.